# Gradle dependency conflict - keep all dependencies versions

Tags: gradle

I see in gradle resolutionStrategy option. However, can't see the option that will keep both versions of a library. Why is that?

Comment: Why would you need to use 2 versions of the same library?

Comment: Let's say that library's update crashes something in my SDK, but in my project that uses this SDK, I wanna use the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in Gradle to use two different versions of the same library at the same time.

However, if you wanted to use different versions for different builds you can do that by creating separate configurations (in Android these could be different build variants).

Comment: I wanna do it only if my SDK has a different version of dependency than my project, so build variants don't make sense here, do they? I have an idea to repackage SDK's dependencies somehow. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by difference between SDK and project?

Comment: by SDK, I mean, a library written by our team. By Project, I mean, a project that uses this library.